# Is it possible to set the initial scroll position (to the end) of a div in HTML (not using javascript)?

Tags: html, scroll

I am working on a system that has a websockets based chat facility. If the user refreshes their page, the previous chats are populated in the HTML when the page loads. The problem is that they are not scrolled to the latest chat.

I know I can set the scroll position using javsascript once it is loaded, but I was wondering if there was any way in the HTML to indicate that it should start scrolled all the way to the bottom?

Very simplified HTML:

```
<div class="chat-window" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:200px;">
    <div class="message">blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There might be a way to do it with HTML, but JavaScript was designed to address challenges like this. It's actually quite easy to do it, depending on your exact use case. Why the opposition against using it?

Comment: Partly learning, partly because if it can start scrolled to the bottom why use javascript to do it?

Comment: As a side note, I already use javascript to scroll as messages come in, which is more what I feel javascript was designed for - making stuff happen dynamically. In this case it's not a dynamic page change I'm after, it's the static starting position. I can get to that starting position by adding js to do it dynamically, but if I can just start it there with HTML then it would make more sense to do so.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. [This article](https://blog.eqrion.net/pin-to-bottom/) suggests it's doable but it doesn't seem to be working for me in Chrome. Seems like [this js](http://jsfiddle.net/nT75k/2/) solution is your best bet.

Comment: The article is one that keeps the scroll at the bottom, I'm just wondering if it is possible to start at the bottom. If js is the only option, I have js I can already re-use

Comment: Your chat relies on JS to function anyway: just use JS to scroll down also. You won't gain any significant performance by using html/css only. Focus on results first then on refactoring.

Comment: It would be architecturally cleaner in my case to do it without the JS. That will be my preference, if it can be done, which is what I am trying to determine. It's not an issue to do it with js, I'm not trying to argue against that, just wanting to know if the ideal way is possible or not.